# dropdown menu does not cover the text underneath /z-index

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vINV.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf1FY.jpg)Hi I have created a drop down menu. I want to inject it in a navigation. when drop down menu opens it jumps in the navigation and makes the height longer. I don't want that it happens I want it opens on the cloud so don't change the navigation height, I tried to use z-index but did not work!
below find my codes plz:

```css
    .social{
     height:50px;
     text-align: center;
     width:70pt;
     cursor:pointer; 
     position: absolute;
     
    }
    
    .first{
     padding-top:5px;
     height: 25pt ;
     color:white;
     background:black;
    
    }
    
    
    .second{
     z-index:5;
     padding-top:5px;
     height: 25pt ;
     display:none;
    }
    
    .social:hover .first{
     background:@gray-dark ;
     .first-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
     }
    }
    
    .social:hover .second {
     background:white;
     display:block;
     color:grey;
     .second-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
    
     }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="social">
       <div class="first">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-facebook first first-hover" ></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-twitter first first-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon icon-instagram first first-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
      <div class="second">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-youtube second second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class=" icon icon-twitter second second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon icon-pintrest second second-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    
      <div>
        dsfsdfdsfsdf
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understood exactly what are you trying to do but if you want a parent container not changing its size depending on it's children, you could try `position: absolute` on the children

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it did not work ! I have attached an image just to make it more clear . when user hovers on the icons a drop down menu opens that I want to covers the text but mine does not cover the text but push the text down when it opens

Comment: *"cloud"*? what? I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did it: I used position:absolute in second and position:relative in its wrapper .social . Then I changed the positioning of the height and width rules.

```css
body{ background: green; }

.social{
     height:50px;
     text-align: center;
     width:70pt;
     cursor:pointer; 
     position:relative;
     
    }
    
    .first{
     padding-top:5px;
     height: 25pt ;
     color:white;
     background:black;
    }
    
    
    .second{
     
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
     z-index:10;
    display: none;
     
      background: yellow;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .second .list-inline{
      
    }
    
    .second .list-inline li{
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
    
     .social:hover .first{
     background:@gray-dark ;
     .first-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
     }
    }
    
    .social:hover .second {
     background:white;
     display:block;
     color:grey;
     .second-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
    
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social">
       <div class="first">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="fa fa-facebook first first-hover" ></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="fa fa-twitter first first-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa fa-instagram first first-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
      <div class="second">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="fa fa-youtube  second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="fa fa-twitter  second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa fa-pinterest  second-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    
      <div>
        dsfsdfdsfsdf
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well I changed the codes it works drop down menu covers the text it is fine but the problem is drop down menu width decreases and all the icons sticks to each other in the drop down menu. I will insert the picture of the result I think it helps  http://i.stack.imgur.com/DnRq4.jpg

Comment: Still not, it pushes the text down !

Comment: @Neg try now, I changed my solution, seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

Try do adjust positioning and z-index of your unordered list and the width of it as well.

```css
    .social{
     height:50px;
     text-align: center;
     width:70pt;
     cursor:pointer; 
     position: absolute;
     
    }
    
    .first{
     padding-top:5px;
     height: 25pt ;
     color:white;
     background:black;
    
    }
    
    .social:hover .second ul{
       display:block;
       width:100%;
       position: relative;
       z-index:1111;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }
    .second{
     z-index:5;
     padding-top:5px;
     height: 25pt ;
     display:none;
    }
    
    .social:hover .first{
     background:@gray-dark ;
     .first-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
     }
    }
    
    .social:hover .second {
     background:white;
     display:block;
     color:grey;
     .second-hover:hover{
      color:@blue;
    
     }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="social">
       <div class="first">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-facebook first first-hover" ></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-twitter first first-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon icon-instagram first first-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
      <div class="second">
         <ul class="Header-social list-inline right">
           <li >
             <a  href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">
               <i class="icon icon-youtube second second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
             <a  href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
               <i class=" icon icon-twitter second second-hover"></i>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li >
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon icon-pintrest second second-hover"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>  
      </div>
    
      <div>
        dsfsdfdsfsdf
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: well nothing happens !